# How do I join these 5 tables?

Tags: mysql, join

ENGINE InnoDB

Table A

```
Id_A INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
NameA VARCHAR;
SurnameA VARCHAR;
```

Table B

```
Id_B INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
NameB VARCHAR;
SurnameB VARCHAR;
```

Table C

```
Id_C INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
Des VARCHAR;
```

Table D

```
Id_D INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
Date_Time DATETIME;
Id_A INT;
Id_B INT;
Id_C INT;
```

Table E

```
Id_E INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
Date DATE;
Time TIME;
NameA VARCHAR;
SurnameA VARCHAR;
NameB VARCHAR;
SurnameB VARCHAR;
Des VARCHAR;
```

I have imported data into Table A and Table E from txt file. ALso added unique data from Table E to Tabe B and Table C. Now I have to add data into Table D (the ID number from A, B, C to match the Date and Time from Table E). I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Table E very much looks like a wrong modelization idea.

Comment: Table E will be deleted and basically will be replaced by Table D. I've been told that I need to add more columns (for help) to Table E but I'm stuck (this is my first project in mysql). Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO TableD (Date_Time, Id_A, Id_B, Id_C)
SELECT TIMESTAMP(e.Date, e.Time),
       a.Id_A,
       b.Id_B,
       c.Id_C
FROM TableE e
INNER JOIN TableA a on e.NameA = a.NameA AND e.SurnameA = a.SurnameA
INNER JOIN TableB b on e.NameB = b.NameB AND e.SurnameB = b.SurnameB
INNER JOIN TableC c on e.Des = c.Des
```

Please be aware that this way of importing will fail if you have some people with same name/surname in either your table A or B, or if table C's Des is not unique.

Comment: Thanks man, worked great! Cheers and have a relaxing week-end!